# Reset button in Exposed Form of Views

Tags: views

I have a view named `search-form`. In my view there are some fields like age, profession, education, etc. In this view I am using 2 buttons i.e. Submit & Reset. These buttons show from **Exposed Form** setting of View.

**Submit** button is working fine but whenever I click on the **Reset** button. It works like submit button. I have check through firebug. Found this `<input type="submit" id="edit-reset" name="op" value="Reset" class="form-submit">`. I think in place of 'submit', 'reset' need to set. How can I solve this. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Use `str_replace()` function

`$variables['page']=str_replace(your replace code);` in your template.php within `themename_preprocess_html()` fuction.

You can replace **type="submit"** with what you want i.e **type="reset"**.

Rough Example

```
$variables['page']=str_replace('<input type="submit" id="edit-reset" name="op" value="Reset" class="form-submit">','<input type="reset" id="edit-reset" name="op" value="Reset" class="form-submit">',$variables['page']);
```

Answer (score 3):

Download and install the [**Better Exposed Filters**](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) module. This module provides a "Include Reset button" when you are creating a View.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually this issue occurs in my live site & client don't want to use any module.

Comment: Ok. Please refer this article
http://www.zyxware.com/articles/3335/solved-drupal-views-how-to-add-a-reset-button-to-a-views-exposed-filters

Tell me if it helps you.

Comment: same issue with this module also. I think something went wrong.

Comment: Have you tried writing custom code as explained in above mentioned link ?

Comment: No I can't try to create new custom module any more.